# Find $n$ such that the numerator of $1+\frac{1}2+\frac{1}3+\cdots+\frac{1}n$ is a square number

Tags: number-theory

Let $$a_n=1+\frac{1}2+\frac{1}3+\cdots+\frac{1}n=\frac{p_n}{q_n},$$ 
where $gcd(p_n,q_n)=1.$

$$\{a_n\}=\left\{1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{11}{6},\frac{25}{12},\frac{137}{60},\frac{49}{20},\frac{363}{140},\cdots\right\}$$

Hence $p_1=1,p_4=5^2,p_6=7^2,$ are there any other $n$ such that $\sqrt{p_n}\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: If it helps, the numerators are known as [Wolstenholme numbers](http://oeis.org/A001008). I don't think there are more squares in it.

Comment: [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem) implies that if $n$ is prime then $n^2|p_{n-1}$.

Comment: And the conjecture is that for $n$ prime, the numerator divided by $n^2$ is square-free.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I believe you mean that for $n$ prime, $\frac{p_{n-1}} { n^2}$ is square free? However, that is equal to 1 for $p=5, 7$, as demonstrated by OP.

Comment: Yes, the conjecture in math.uci.edu/~tchoi/notes/wolstenholme.pdf, last page.

Comment: @CalvinLin But I believe they can be shown to grow so swiftly that equality can't hold for any higher values - those are just small-$n$ coincidences.

Answer (score 1):

Not a demonstration, but I tested with mathematica up to $n=1000$ (is now running up to $10000$) and the only one that mathematica found were $1$, $25$ und $49$.

Updated: up to $10000$ nothing more :-)

Simple code if someone is interested

```
f[n_] := Sum[1/i, {i, n}];
Nf[n_] := Numerator[f[n]];
IsSqr[x_] := IntegerQ[Sqrt[x]];
Do[
 If[IsSqr[Nf[i]],
  Print[Nf[i]], ], {i, 10000}]
```

Comment: This should be a comment, I believe, not an answer.

Comment: The problem was I could not add a comment. Didn't have the option. Does it depends on reputation?

Comment: It does, you need 50 reputation to comment on other someone else's post. I mean it's okay, posting an answer like that isn't the worse offense you could commit.

Comment: Thanks :-) Now I got 89 and I can comment. Thanks for the hint.